# Couchdb: sort by version

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

Is there an elegant approach to sort by version field (stored as string) in Couchdb?

That is, if I have a version schema like this *major.minor.build.revision* (5.5.1.14), how can I emit the key to make sure following statements go in that certain order:

```
4.2.3.40
5.2.3.4
5.2.3.40
5.2.4.30
5.2.601.52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are talking about a map/reduce function, given that assumption there is an easy solution:

Simply split your version key by the `.` and emit that array directly. CouchDB's [view collation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/collation.html) will have the keys sorted the way you probably expect.

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.version.split('.'));
}
```

You can even use the [`group_level`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=group_level) view parameter to aggregate your versions by each tier/level. First, add the following as your reduce function:

```
_count
```

This is a [built-in reduce function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#builtin-reduce-functions) that will count the number of rows in a given query.

Given the following values for `group_level`, you'll see the following results. (given your example documents)

- 1 (groups by "major" version)

  - key: 4, value: 1
  - key: 5, value: 4
- 2 (groups by "minor" version)

  - key: 4.2, value: 1
  - key: 5.2, value: 4
- 3 (groups by "patch" version)

  - key: 4.2.3, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.3, value: 2
  - key: 5.2.4, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.601, value: 1
- 4 (you can also just use `group=true` for this case)

  - key: 4.2.3.40, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.3.4, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.3.40, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.4.30, value: 1
  - key: 5.2.601.52, value: 1